# (Escapable) sandboxed REPL over socket?

Tags: sockets, racket

Recently I have used Guile which allows to redirect its REPL to a socket which is pretty neat. Then I found the following code on [the Wikipedia page of Racket features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racket_features#Resource_Management_and_Sandboxing). I'll paste the code here for your convenience:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/sandbox)
(define e (make-evaluator 'racket/base))
(let-values ([(i o) (tcp-accept (tcp-listen 9999))])
  (parameterize ([current-input-port  i]
                 [current-output-port o]
                 [current-error-port  o]
                 [current-eval e]
                 [current-read-interaction (λ (x in) (read in))])
    (read-eval-print-loop)
    (fprintf o "\nBye...\n")
    (close-output-port o)))
```

To my understanding, this should create a new (sandboxed!) REPL over a TCP-socket with all in- and output being redirected to run over it. But when I try this with (Dr)Racket 6.0 it doesn't quite work. I can connect to the socket (using netcat) and issue commands (i.e. "(+ 1 2)"), but the result isn't sent back, instead the result appears in DrRacket's interaction window. From reading the documentation I guess I might need to parameterize "current-print", but I am not sure how to do that correctly.

How can I make it so that I have a full REPL over socket communications?
Also I would like the sandbox to be escapable for certain functions that I define myself. What would be the best approach for that?

Regards

Comment: Although I'm not sure exactly why it doesn't work running it using the DrRacket IDE, do you need to run it that way? I ask because it works fine for me running it using command-line Racket.

Comment: As for the second part of your question, I'm not sure what you mean. Could you describe an example of a function you'd want to escape the sandbox, what would it need to do?

Comment: I have actually not tried to do it with command-line-Racket, I used the IDE because it was more convenient and I assumed the behavior would be the same. I guess I'll try that tomorrow :) As for "escaping the sand box": I read that the sandbox can be configured in ways so that i.e. no file access is possible. And that's a good thing. However, I would like to write a function that has access to the filesystem (and other resources) as sort of a "safe frontend" for the user of the REPL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for explaining more in the comments. Although I might still be misunderstanding, here's an answer for what I *think* you mean.

Your REPL could support commands, much like Racket's XREPL. So at the prompt you type `,pwd`, and it treats it as a "command" not a Racket expression.

The command can do privileged things that user code running *inside* the sandboxed REPL can't do.

The user in the REPL will get an error attempting to do this:

```
(find-files (lambda (_) #t) (current-directory))
```

However you can implement a `,pwd` command that is allowed to do that, for example by supplying your own `current-prompt-read` handler:

```
#lang racket

(require racket/sandbox)

(define (our-prompt-read)  ;; <-- NEW
  (display "> ")
  (flush-output (current-output-port))
  (define in ((current-get-interaction-input-port)))
  (define stx ((current-read-interaction) (object-name in) in))
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(uq cmd)
     (eq? 'unquote (syntax-e #'uq))
     (case (syntax-e #'cmd)
       [(pwd) (displayln (find-files (lambda (_) #t) (current-directory)))])]
    [_ stx]))

(define e (make-evaluator 'racket/base))
(let-values ([(i o) (tcp-accept (tcp-listen 9999))])
  (parameterize ([current-input-port  i]
                 [current-output-port o]
                 [current-error-port  o]
                 [current-eval e]
                 [current-read-interaction (λ (x in) (read in))]
                 [current-prompt-read our-prompt-read])  ;; <--- NEW
    (read-eval-print-loop)
    (fprintf o "\nBye...\n")
    (close-output-port o)))
```

Comment: Well, running from the command line works, so that's good :) Let me try again to explain what I am trying to achieve: I have a module that's doing certain things (deleting, copying and moving files, writing logs, etc). Now I'd like to somehow use this over a network connection. So I figured that providing a restricted REPL which can freely call that module's functions but cannot do anything else that I have no control over (or at least nothing that can break something) would be both the easiest and the most flexible way to go.

Comment: Also I am not sure how to use that pwd command, it just tells me `> (pwd)  pwd: undefined; cannot reference an identifier before its definition`.

Comment: At the REPL prompt you'd type `,pwd` -- a comma followed by "pwd".

Comment: OK, so it sounds like you don't really want a full Racket REPL. Instead you want a simple protocol with specific commands for the operations like delete, move, log, and so on.

Comment: Basically, yes. I was just assuming that using stuff that's already there (the REPL over socket) would be easier and less error-prone than implementing the whole protocol over a tcp-socket by hand.